# Error messages when removing hooks from class component - Role Based Access Nav Bar

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am trying to create a header using Material UI/ Redux / React that has a drop down menu that only displays sections that a user has access to. I have partially changed my code as the examples I was originally using had hooks in a component class but i'm now getting different error messsages.

How do I define the below? I already have them added to my constructor.

```
Line 41:35:   'anchorEl' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 42:38:   'mobileMoreAnchorEl' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 43:27:   'anchorEl' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 44:33:   'mobileMoreAnchorEl' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 90:25:   'currentTarget' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 103:34:  'currentTarget' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 109:23:  'anchorEl' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 114:19:  'isMenuOpen' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 126:23:  'mobileMoreAnchorEl' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 131:19:  'isMobileMenuOpen' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 222:69:  'preventDefault' is not defined      no-undef
```

header.Component.js

```
class ScubaNavbar extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.logOut = this.logOut.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      showUserLevelAccess: false,
      showSchoolLevelAccess: false,
      showAdminLevelAccess: false,
      currentUser: undefined,
      **anchorEl: null,
      setAnchorEl: null,
      mobileMoreAnchorEl: Boolean(anchorEl),
      setMobileMoreAnchorEl: Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl),
      isMenuOpen: Boolean(anchorEl),
      isMobileMenuOpen: Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl),**
    };

    history.listen((location) => {
      props.dispatch(clearMessage());
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    const user = this.props.user;
    console.log(user)
    if (user) {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: user,
        showUserLevelAccess: user.userRoles === 1,
        showSchoolLevelAccess: user.userRoles === 2,
        showSiteAdminLevelAccess: user.userRoles === 3,
      });
    }
  }

  logOut() {
    this.props.dispatch(logout());
  }

  render() {

    const {
      // current user gives specific user details
      currentUser,
      // levels give role access
      showUserLevelAccess,
      showSchoolLevelAccess,
      showSiteAdminLevelAccess,
    } = this.state;

    const { classes } = this.props;

    // const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    // const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    //
    // const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
    // const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);

    **const handleProfileMenuOpen =() => {
       this.setAnchorEl(currentTarget);
    };
    const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
      this.setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
    };
    const handleMenuClose = () => {
      this.setAnchorEl(null);
      handleMobileMenuClose();
    };
    const handleMobileMenuOpen = () => {
      this.setMobileMoreAnchorEl(currentTarget);
    };**

    const menuId = 'dark-search-account-menu';
    const renderMenu = (
        <Menu
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right'}}
            id={menuId}
            keepMounted
            transformOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right'}}
            open={isMenuOpen}
            onClose={handleMenuClose}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    );

    const mobileMenuId = 'dark-search-account-menu-mobile';

    const renderMobileMenu = (
        <Menu
            anchorEl={mobileMoreAnchorEl}
            anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right'}}
            id={mobileMenuId}
            keepMounted
            transformOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right'}}
            open={isMobileMenuOpen}
            onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
        >
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to write your component as a functional component and keep using hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misconception of how variable scopes work in javascript. The values you are trying to access are in `this.state` which you can access from the `render()` method:

```
<Menu
    anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
    // ...
>
```

To access a variable it needs to be defined and in scope. The `render()` method does not share a scope with the `constructor()` and by adding them to `this.state` they will not suddenly be accessible in `render()` just by using the same names you used for the properties in `this.state`.

I suggest you read about how variable [scope](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript) works in javascript: